# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '*'

Tags: python, pytorch

Ошибка следующая `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '8'.`
в [этом](https://github.com/OniroAI/MonoDepth-PyTorch) проекте с гит хаба.

Задача такая. Нужно модель загрузить с параметрами и испытать.

Параметры выставляются такие.

```
dict_parameters = edict({'data_dir':'/content/MonoDepth-PyTorch/data/kitti/train/',
                         'val_data_dir':'/content/MonoDepth-PyTorch/data/kitti/val/',
                         'model_path':'/content/MonoDepth-PyTorch/data/models/monodepth_resnet18_001.pth',
                         'output_directory':'/content/MonoDepth-PyTorch/data/output/',
                         'input_height':256,
                         'input_width':512,
                         'model':'resnet18_md',
                         'pretrained':True,
                         'mode':'test',
                         'epochs':200,
                         'learning_rate':1e-4,
                         'batch_size': 8,
                         'adjust_lr':True,
                         'device':'cpu',
                         'do_augmentation':True,
                         'augment_parameters':[0.8, 1.2, 0.5, 2.0, 0.8, 1.2],
                         'print_images':False,
                         'print_weights':False,
                         'input_channels': 3,
                         'num_workers': 8,
                         'use_multiple_gpu': False})
```

Дефолтные параметры были мной изменены. А именно: пути к папкам, мод поменял на тест вместо трейн (логично :) )
и девайс на цпу, гпу google colab почему то не разрешил.

модель загружается так:

```
model = Model(dict_parameters)
```

ошибку можно посмотреть на колабе по [ссылке](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/128TZmSlbPonnDfms3IfeoCmmgYIOllZl#scrollTo=CW60zvxWuW65&line=1&uniqifier=1)

К сожалению даже не знаю как понять из за чего это может быть. Направьте пожалуйста в верном направлении))

Comment: Нет доступа к колабу, я запросил доступ )

Comment: вообщем я плюнул на колаб, перенёс весь код и модель на пк. С некоторыми сложностями запустил... Ошибка такого рода не вылезла. Однако dict_parameters для теста и для тренировки разные. Я набивал dict_parameters из трейна для теста. Возможно в этом была ошибка.